# How can I set the Button visible?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, visible

my problem is, that even though I set button visible property "true" by using setVisible(true) but the button is still not visible.  When I inspect the Button isVisible is shown as true, but the button isn't there

I added let the system print stuff out, after very important line of code and the message after the setVisible has been printed too.

```
public void buttonarrays(){
       inGame = new JButton(); 
       inGame.setVisible(true); 
       inventory = new JButton();
       inventory.setVisible(false);
       add(inGame);
       add(inventory);


           inGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                   if(true){

                       switch(0) {
                           case 0:
                           inventory.setVisible(true);
                           inGame.setVisible(false);
                           break;
                       }
                   }
           }
     });
    }
```

I tried to minimize it and hope u still understand what I mean

Comment: Well, your button neither has any text nor an icon so depending on the container's layout manager it will probably be very small. Speaking of layout managers: which one does your class use? What type of component is that method in (`add(inGame)` indicates your class extends some container component)? Did you add your container to the frame/window (maybe with intermediate containers)? What layout do those use?

Comment: Hint: you can't learn swing/awt from making experiments. These frameworks require a certain level of knowledge in order to do something useful for you. Just thinking up some code based on "hmm, this might work", rest assured: it will not work. Instead: get a good book, or simple the oracle tutorial ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html ) and read/work with **working** example code. What you do here ... pulling together some ideas, honestly: you are waisting your time and energy.

Comment: It has an icon, I just took it out, so it's less code for u

Answer (score 0):

This is working code of button 
Please try it, learn it and then try to find what problem you are making in your code.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
public class JButtonExample {
    JButtonExample(){  

        JFrame frame=new JFrame();  

        // Creating Button          
        JButton b=new JButton("Click Me..");

        b.setBounds(50,50,90, 50);  

        //Adding button onto the frame
        frame.add(b);  

        // Setting Frame size. This is the window size
        frame.setSize(300,200);  

        frame.setLayout(null);  
        frame.setVisible(true);  

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

    }  

     public static void main(String[] args) {  
            new JButtonExample();  
     }  
}
```